# Saving drawing in separate pieces

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a Visio file (that I am able to edit it) that looks like this:

[image]

I want to cut it in separate pieces(A4 pages). I know, that there is a way to select piece that you want to save, and then save, but when I try to do it, I can't select some lines, or names or etc. But when I push Ctrl+A everything selects just perfectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is it you really want to accomplish?  If you want to print it out and tape the pages together to make one large sheet, there are ways to do that.  Search for "print poster multiple pages" (for example).

If you really are trying to split the drawing up into smaller ones, and you can't select items individually, they might be grouped together into larger pieces.  You have to ungroup them first.

If you can't do that, maybe you are running into a problem like the one discussed in the following (related to protections being set on the group or having bitmap images in there)

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-visio/not-able-to-ungroup-a-visio-drowing/8dd078ed-d9a0-4444-9354-548ab6bbfed4

Comment: Be very careful with suggesting ungrouping. Ungrouping shapes that you haven't grouped yourself will probably seriously break many shapes.

Answer (score 0):

The normal option when selecting shapes is to not select a shape unless it is totally within the select area. You can change this in **Options -> Advanced**.

However, guessing what you actually want to do, save your diagram as an image (PNG is good), then load it into an image editor and save suitable sized areas as individual images.